# Content in footer file

Tags: content, footer

I swear I've done this before, but I am drawing a blank on it now...

I'm trying to get it so that I can have editable content in my footer.php file.  So that I (or the user) can update the content within the pages area.

But I can't remember how to go about it, or if I need to do a widget instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways this can be achieved.

You can create a theme option for the area. I used this as a theme option starter when I built a theme recently: [Sample theme options](http://themeshaper.com/2010/06/03/sample-theme-options/)

Or

You can simply create a widget area for the footer http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes

Comment: DAP!  It's the widgets that I was looking for.  Thanks for the input!